# How to use the passed data in to a sql query?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

How do I pass the `$id` into my `$record` SQL query and what is the eloquent query as well?

I want to do this because the `user_id` is the foreign key from `borrows`. I want to pull data from `payment_records` that have the same `id` with the selected `id`.

This is the `show` method where I passed the `id` and do the query:

```php
public function show($id)
{
    //the eloquent pull from borrows
    $borrows = borrows::find($id);

    $record = DB::select('SELECT `id`, `balance`, `amount_due`, `current_balance`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `user_id` FROM `payment_records` WHERE user_id = 45');
    
    // $borrows = DB::select('select * from borrows, payment_records where id = $id');
    
    return view('borrows.show')->with('borrows', $borrows)->with('record',$record);
}
```

This is the query where I want to use the `id` to compare with `user_id`:

```php
$record = DB::select('SELECT `id`, `balance`, `amount_due`, `current_balance`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `user_id` FROM `payment_records` WHERE user_id = 45');
```

Comment: `select(..` doesn't need `SELECT` in it. Or `FROM`, or `WHERE`. [Select Statements](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#select-statements).

Comment: Read [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-a-select-query) about raw queries and how you can use parameters in them however I do highly recommend using the [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries) especially when using queries as simple as this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are after something similar:

```php
$users = DB::table('payment_records')
             ->select('id', 'balance', 'amount_due', 'current_balance', 'created_at', 'updated_at','user_id')
             ->where('user_id', '=', $id) // `$id` is used here
             ->get();
```

Comment: im sure this is the right answer but it returns an error ::SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id, balance, amount_due, current_balance, created_at, updated_at,user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `id, balance, amount_due, current_balance, created_at, updated_at,user_id` from `payment_records` where `user_id` = 48)

Comment: each column is meant to be a single string so it should be `select('id', 'balance', 'amount_due', 'current_balance', 'created_at', 'updated_at','user_id')`

Answer (score 0):

You must use double-quote instead of single-quote

```php
        $record = DB::raw("SELECT `id`, `balance`, `amount_due`, `current_balance`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `user_id` FROM `payment_records` WHERE user_id = $id");
```